# BIRT 431: Java/JDBC for Oracle compatibility issue

Tags: oracle, eclipse, jdbc, birt, maximo

*BIRT 431; Oracle 12c*

*IBM Maximo Asset Management 7.6.1.2 — only supports BIRT 431*

---

I want to preview my BIRT reports (by connecting from BIRT to the Maximo database).

BIRT 431 requires Java 7. However, the latest version of JDBC for Oracle requires Java 8 (older drivers won't connect to the database).

If that's correct, then how can I preview BIRT reports if BIRT 431 doesn't support any functioning JDBC drivers?

Comment: _"older drivers won't connect to the database"_ that is incorrect, or otherwise you need to at least provide the error you get when connecting. You can for example use the Oracle JDBC 12.1.0.2 driver from https://www.oracle.com/database/technologies/jdbc-upc-downloads.html, older Oracle drivers can usually connect to newer Oracle versions. Also, if BIRT 431 requires Java 7, that doesn't necessarily mean it doesn't work on Java 8, 'requires' usually means it doesn't work on **lower** versions. Have you actually tried with Java 8?

Answer (score 1):

*A colleague provided this solution. I haven't been able to test it yet.*

---

Use the latest available version of the jdbc driver for Oracle designed for Java 7:

- [Oracle Database 12.1.0.1 JDBC Driver & UCP Downloads](https://www.oracle.com/database/technologies/jdbc-drivers-12c-downloads.html) `-->` **ojdbc7.jar**

---

In order to get preview features working for Eclipse BIRT 4.3.1 the following steps need to be taken:

1. Be sure that the version of Java being used for Eclipse is version 7.  If it isn’t change it to version 7 as the preview feature will not work with 8.
2. Review chapter 2 in the attached document.
3. Save the attached file (ojdbc7.jar.txt) to the folder eclipse\plugins\org.eclipse.birt.report.viewer_4.3.1.v201309171028\birt\WEB-INF\lib below your base eclipse installation folder.  Rename the file removing the “.txt”.
4. Create a copy of the file and change the extension from “.jar” to “.zip”.
5. Extract the contents of the zip file to eclipse\plugins\org.eclipse.birt.report.viewer_4.3.1.v201309171028\birt\WEB-INF\classes
6. Confirm Eclipse configuration as per the documentation from point 2.
7. Test with a report to confirmation functionality.
8. If there is an issue with the built in tool for previewing report output you may need to configure Eclipse to use a web browser instead.
9. In Eclipse use Window -> Preferences -> Report Design -> Preview.
10. Check the option “Always use external browsers.”
11. Click on the Web Browser link.
12. Click on the “Use external web browser” radio button and check “Default system web browser” or the browser of your choice if it appears in the list.

---

Related:

[Maximo76_Designer431_Report Development Guide_Rev8.pdf](https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/maximo-76designer-431-report-development-guide)

Comment: This does work;

You can also fetch, if you have filesystem access to maximo installation server, the ojdbc lib that maximo uses. (SMP\maximo\applications\maximo\lib) Maximo BIRT viewer is basically the same one as the one you're using in the designer.